# Mongoose - Least distance between two co-ordinates (Not GEOJson Data)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

From a list of buildings, the operator will choose one.

and click on it from the front end.

The list of buildings is stored in the MongoDB database and each one has a x,y point demonstrating distance from the 0 origin.

The list is stored in MongoDB database and accessed with node.

Each building has a x,y co-ordinate -- sample only, NOT geojson data

like 101,203 etc.

The Mongoose function will :

1. Operator clicks on a button and that co-ordinates are used
2. The funciton will search  through the list of buildings and return the nearest one to the one provided --- not the nearest one to the 0 origin.

Any suggestions on how to do with Mongoose?

thanks!
Karen

Comment: Are x,y coord always positive, i.e. this is a single quadrant system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really just a math problem.
Consider a set of building docs with these `x,y` coords:

```js
var r =   [
    {_id:1, x:7, y:11}
    ,{_id:2, x:15, y:10}
    ,{_id:3, x:10, y:9}
    ,{_id:4, x:1, y:8}
    ,{_id:5, x:3, y:7}
    ,{_id:6, x:16, y:5}
    ,{_id:7, x:4, y:3}
    ,{_id:8, x:7, y:3}
    ,{_id:9, x:6, y:1}
    ,{_id:10, x:21, y:1}
];
```

A button is clicked and produces point `6,5`:

```js
var P = {x:6, y:5};
```

To find buildings closest, just iterate and compute distance using pythagorean theorem:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    //  Don't have to worry about absolute value of x-x1 thanks to                                         
    //  pow(2) making it positive                                                                          
    //  dist = sqrt((x-x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2)                                                                   
    {$addFields: {dist: {$sqrt: {$add:[{$pow:[{$subtract:['$x',P.x]},2]}, {$pow:[{$subtract:['$y',P.y]},2]}]}} }},
    {$sort: {'dist':1}},
    {$limit: 1}
]);

{ "_id" : 8, "x" : 7, "y" : 3, "dist" : 2.23606797749979 }
```

Remove the `$limit` or change it to a higher number to see the next closest buidlings.

Comment: Its not pythagoras theorem, but Euclidean distance formula.

Comment: That is so awesome! I am ever so grateful :) Thank you very much -- you rock!

Comment: @karentut  You're welcome.  Don't be shy about clicking the Accepted Answer checkmark.

Comment: @Buzz -- I believe that I have just done that.  Thx again! -- ps I didn't know I could do that.  So thanks again for letting me know that was an option.